SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in Pump 3.0.1
Around 10:30 PST today Sept 10 2024 my ng build command suddenly started giving this error on ng build.  Yes I know I'm on an old build and I recognize the answer probably is "Upgrade everything to the latest," but if there is another answer that'd be cool.
    Unexpected token {
/Users/MattWh@vsp.com/git/provider-fee-ui/node_modules/pump/index.js:7
} catch {}
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MattWh@vsp.com/git/provider-fee-ui/node_modules/mississippi/index.js:1:85)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)


    ng v


     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 7.0.7
Node: 8.9.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.10
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.10
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.7
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      7.0.7
@angular/flex-layout              7.0.0-beta.24
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.10
@schematics/angular               7.0.7
@schematics/update                0.10.7
rxjs                              5.6.0-forward-compat.5
typescript                        3.1.8
webpack                           4.29.0

node -v
v8.9.0

npm -v
5.5.1


Can you provide a [mre]?

Answering my own question -
Looks like pump 3.0.1 is not compatible with Angular 7.  I performed a
npm install pump@3.0.0
Which put the following in my package.json
"pump": "^3.0.0",
Which I then had to modify to
"pump": "3.0.0",
and then the compile error went away on my ng build

Don't know if it is because of Angular 7 but pump 3.0.1 makes a try catch without using an error parameter:
try {
  fs = require('fs') // we only need fs to get the ReadStream and WriteStream prototypes
} catch {}

This is supported starting with JS specification ECMAScript 2019/ES10.
So this might be the problem behind.
